# Variable cast to double in printf produces random output

Tags: c, gcc, casting, floating-point, printf

I was trying to see the hex representation of floating point numbers and compiled this code with gcc-4.9.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double i = 100;

  printf("%f %x\n", i, (double)i);

  return 0;
}
```

I was surprised to find that everytime I ran the code the hex value printed out changed. What is going on? How can I safely print the hex representation of a floating point number?

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour induces undefined responses — and your code certainly invokes undefined behaviour.  The cast is immaterial; it converts a `double` value into a `double`, which is a no-op.  To print the hex digits, you'd need to pass the address of the `double` into a function and have that function print the bytes in turn — something like: `void print_double_in_hex(void *dp) { unsigned char *ptr = vp; for (i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) printf("%x", *ptr++); }` and `print_double_in_hex(&i);` as the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%x` format specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. You're giving it an argument of type `double`. The behavior is undefined, which means that as far as the C standard is concerned *anything* can happen -- including changing the output for other specifiers in the same format string.

To print the hex representation of a floating-point number, copy it to an array of `unsigned char` and print the elements of the array.

Answer (score 2):

To print the hexadecimal representation of a double, you must cast the double to an array of `char` and then print each byte:

```
double i = 100;
int j;
for (j=0; j<sizeof(double);j++)
    printf("%x\n", ((unsigned char *)&i)[j]);
```

with `((char *)&i)` you take the address of `i` and tell the compiler to interpret it as a pointer to `char`. Next you treat that pointer as an array of `char` and index it.

Note that type `unsigned char` is used so if any byte has its left most bit set to 1, it will not be sign-extended when it is turned into an `int` before it is passed to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%x` is used for objects of integral types. It considers the corresponding argument as an object of type unsigned int. Take into account that for arguments of integral types there is applied the integer promotion.

So the function behavior is undefined when the specifier is used for floating numbers.

Comment: `%x` is used only for an argument of type `unsigned int`, not integral types in general.

Comment: @KeithThompson You may use objects of signed types as arguments for the parameter of unsigned type if they can be represented in the unsigned type. And more over there the integral promotion.

Comment: I should have written "*promoted* argument of type `unsigned int`, and that's a good point about signed arguments. But you can't, for example, use an argument of an integer type wider than `int`, or a negative value. (In practice you're very likely to get away with the latter, but the behavior is undefined.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, you can not. Nevertheless in general you can  supply objects of signed integer types.:)

Comment: An argument of type `long long` is likely to fail, even if its value is positive. And again, the argument is an expression, not necessarily an object.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I safely print the hex representation of a floating point number?

`"%x"` is for integers like `unsigned`.

To see a hexadecimal representation of a FP number use `"%a"`

```
// mis-match between specifier and argument 
//             v---------^   v-------^
// printf("%f %x\n", i, (double)i);  

double i = 0.1;
printf("%f %a\n", i, i);
```

Output

```
   hexadecimal significant  decimal power-of-2 exponent
           v-------------v  v        
0.100000 0x1.999999999999ap-4
```

Alternatively use a `union`

```
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof (double)];
  } x = {0.1};
  for (unsigned i = sizeof x.uc; i > 0;) {
    printf("%02X", x.uc[--i]);
  }
```

Sample output - which depends on endian and other platform dependencies.  [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) details.

```
+--------------- MS bit: sign 
+-+------------- 11 bit: biased exponent
| |+-----------+ 52-bit: raw fraction
| ||           |
3FB999999999999A
```